# An equilateral triangle has a perimeter of 810 cm. Calculate the area of ​an octagon that has the side equal to 4/9 of the side of the triangle.

Tags: geometry

An equilateral triangle has a perimeter of 810 cm. Calculate the area of ​​an octagon that has the side equal
 to 4/9 of the side of the triangle.

Comment: For the record, you'll be more likely to get more explicit, helpful answers if you specify some context - namely, where this came up, your understanding of the problem, and your attempts. MSE is generally not a "do my homework for me" site and your post comes off as exactly that type of post because it contains nothing but an isolated question. Your point will likely accumulate downvotes and close votes as a result.

Answer (score 2):

**Hints:**

- If the perimeter of an equilateral triangle is $p$, then its side length is $p/3$. This is because it is the same on all sides.
- The area of a regular $n$-gon is given by the formula $A = ans/2$, where $n$ is the number of sides, $s$ the side length, and $a$ the apothem length. Note that $ns$ is also the perimeter, leading to the other formulation as $A = ap/2$.
- A consequence of the above you can derive with trigonometry is that the area of a regular octagon is $A = 2s^2(1+ \sqrt 2)$ for $s$ the side length.

*(This all being on the assumption that the octagon in question is meant to be regular. But at the same time this question is probably meaningless if not.)*